# A Form(?) appears briefly outside of Form1 when adding a control to it

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have a program which creates new `Control`s (actually - `Form`'s with `TopLevel = false`) and puts them on a `Panel` which is on `Form1`.

For some reason, this is usually followed by what seems like a `Form` appearing very briefly *outside* of `Form1`. It's hard to tell exactly what's happening because it's so brief. Perhaps it's `Form1` moving there (and changing its size) and then returning. Or perhaps it's the `Form` that's being put on `Form1` that appears there (though how could that happen at all? It's out of `Form1`!).

I couldn't find anything in the code that might cause it, and the whole code is way too long to post here. (The relevant code is simply: `MyPanel.Controls.Add(newForm);`.)

Is there any known bug that might cause this?

Comment: Can you show some code of how you are declaring / creating the Form..

Comment: Completely non-related, but when reading the question, I initially read it as "A wild Form appears!"

Comment: @DJKRAZE Nope. Too long. But it's a simple class that inherits from `Form` with some initialization like setting its `Size`, adding some `Control`'s to it, etc.

Comment: Well perhaps there is something being done incorrectly within that Init code that's why I asked .. it's going to be rather difficult to get an accurate answer if we are left to only guess what the possibilities in regards to what could be causing this..

Comment: I know. Hence the last line in my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can sort of guess what the code looks like.  The problem with adding a Form to the Controls collection with TopLevel = false is that you have to explicitly make it visible.  This is an odd quirk (aka bug), normally a control automatically becomes visible when you add it to a Controls collection.

So it probably looks like this:

```
var newform = new Form1();
newform.Visible = true;    // or newform.Show()
newform.TopLevel = false;
MyPanel.Controls.Add(newForm);
```

And yes, that can make it visible for a very brief moment, still as a top-level window, if you do something else that causes messages to be dispatched.  Fix it by swapping the Visible and TopLevel property assignments.

If this doesn't help then post a code snippet.

Comment: That was it! Swapped them and it's fixed. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

So you tried adding a Form to a Form's Controls collection and received the exception telling you that you can't add top level controls. To "fix" it, you set the TopLevel property of that Form to false.

That's not the correct fix.

Use a Panel ([or one of its derivatives](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.panel.aspx#inheritanceContinued)) instead.

Comment: No. I did not try... . I just added a Form because I need one. Forms have properties that cannot be (easily) imitated by any other control.

Comment: @ispiro Whatever it is that you are trying to accomplish, using a Form as a child of another Form is not the correct (WinForms) way to do it. If you describe for us the UI behavior you need, we can offer you a better solution.